# How to make a vertical slider that changes with scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, slide

I am working on a landing page that requires to slide content from bottom to top. Similar to https://www.google.com/adsense/start/benefits/ **custom insight** section.

Comment: this could be done with JQ scroll / scrollTop / offset for each element and animation by adding class to the element when reaching the specific offset see this links
https://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-design-animated-sliding-page-elements-with-css/

https://css-tricks.com/slide-in-as-you-scroll-down-boxes/

and/or search in google by this keyword (animated sliding elements).

Comment: Thanks! I got this working with Wow.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not actually scrolling up. The image is sticking to the page like its absolutely positioned till the text column catches up with it. Then it continues. So its like its `position: absolute;` from a certain coordinate to the end coordinate and then gets its style back.

So if you use Javascript to apply absolute positioning to an image when you scroll to a `<div>` and then revert to old css when you scroll past the `<div>` you will get the effect you want. There are lots of plugins that do this too. I found one here:
https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-Stickem

Check out the demo too to see what I mean.